# How to set the value of an HTML drop down box through a C# WebBrowser Object

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have an element on a page I am loading as follows

```
<select name="proxylisttable_length" aria-controls="proxylisttable" class=""><option value="20">20</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="80">80</option></select>
```

I would like to set the value from its default value of "20" to "80". Currently, I have attempted something along the lines of this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement dropDownSelect = browser.Document.GetElementById("proxylisttable_length");

dropDownSelect.SetAttribute("value", "80");
```

The HtmlElement dropDownSelect is a valid reference and the set attribute executes, but no changes occur on the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not use a `WebBrowser` for this, I found Selenium to be the best tool to grab data off live pages.